# Compiled C++ code produces no terminal output, but VSCode debugger does. Using a -static flag fixes this, but is not a viable solution

Tags: c++, environment-variables, vscode-debugger

I want to print all palindromic numbers that are the product of two three-digit numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    for (int i = 999; i > 100; i--) {
        std::cout << "Checking numbers for i=" << i << "\n";
        for (int j = 999; j > 100; j--) {
            int k = i * j;
            int temp_k = k;
            int reverse_k = 0;
            int remainder_k;

            while(temp_k != 0) {
            remainder_k = temp_k % 10;
            reverse_k = reverse_k * 10 + remainder_k;
            temp_k /= 10;
            }
            
            if (k == reverse_k) {
                std::cout << k << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click `Terminal > Run build task`, I get an executable and the following output:

```
Starting build...
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\mydirectory\palindromic.cpp -o C:\mydirectory\palindromic.exe

Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

When I run this executable, a terminal window appears, then closes. There is no output at all (it is not a case of the window closing very quickly due to not closing with `std::cin.get();` ).

However, if I click `Run > Start Debugging`, I get all of the terminal output in VSCode, i.e.

```
[...]
Checking numbers for i=112
84448
65856
48384
42224
29792
23632
Checking numbers for i=111
[...]
```

I have tried reinstalling MSYS2 and I have a PATH variable pointing to `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`.
This has not fixed the issue. Outputs of where for gcc, g++ and gdb:

```
where g++

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe

where gcc

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe

where gdb

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe
```

If I compile in the VS Code terminal using `g++ -Bstatic -static palindrome.cpp` and then run `a.exe`, it works. Statically linking my libraries is not a good fix though.

Comment: Because static linking fixes the problem it might be a problem with the DLLs loaded when not using static linking. Have you tried using a dependency walker to see which DLLs are being loaded? Or it could be something completely different, we are talking about VSCode, so there are a lot of things that could go wrong.

Comment: Open a Windows terminal (not a VSCode terminal). Try running your program from there. Observe what happens. Do you see any error message?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit After running `g++ palindrome.cpp -o palindrome` in command prompt, I am get the same behaviour. No error messages and it successfully compiles, but it is not producing any output before closing.

Comment: @john I've not used a dependency walker before today, but it gives me loads and loads of missing DLLs. I can't seem to figure out how to format it nicely to show the top of the log, but there are load/mismatch errors in kernelbase.dll and kernel32.dll among others.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. `g++` does not run in the default command prompt because required libraries are not in the PATH. After adding C:\msys64\mingw64\bin to PATH, everything compiles and runs as it should. Make sure you don't have old junk from defunct installations of mingw or whatever in your PATH.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Thanks for your efforts. No junk in PATH - absolutely stumped on this.

Comment: @Rhys Well I don't know much about mingw64 but that sounds like a problem. It's probably an environment issue (e.g. the PATH variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2019 instead of VS Code allowed me to compile executables that behave as expected. Reinstalling VS Code also allows me to compile executables that behave as expected.

Comment: I imagine what has happened is that installing Visual Studio 2019 has placed the correct DLLs in the correct locations (and maybe fixed the environment as well).